# Grep multiple files and save output to different columns

Tags: awk, command-line, grep

Using mac command line, I want to grep multiple files and save output to different columns.

Here is an example of one of my files ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_AP013294 (click 'send to', 'file' save format as 'full genbank file'). I have ~2000 of these. I just want LOCUS (this is unique to each file and there is always one of them) and then every time it has tRNA-, e.g. tRNA-Glu (tRNA- appears throughout the document, there could be ~zero to 200 of these).

This works when I do it on one of the files:

```
grep -e "LOCUS-" -e "tRNA-" *.gbff > output.txt
```

but I would like the `output.txt` file to contain columns, one for each `*.gbff` file:

```
LOCUS XXXX     LOCUS XXXX
tRNA-Glu        tRNA-Asn
tRNA-Ser        tRNA-Ile
                tRNA-Glu
```

... etc.

Comment: is the number of matching lines for each input file same? is it known value? for example 2 in given sample

Comment: what if `doc2.txt` does not contain both `term1` and `term2` ?

Comment: @Sundeep No, the number of lines will vary a lot

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest both terms will always be contained in the files, but the number of rows will vary a lot (i.e. there might be 20 instances of term 1 in doc1 and 15 instances in doc2)

Comment: in that case, you will have to post process the output, say using awk... grep will add filename for each output line which can be used..

Comment: @Sundeep I know the maximum number of lines, if that helps? 200 will be the max...

Comment: I don't see how.. as far as I know, grep doesn't have an option to already do this.. so, you either iterate over file one by one and manually build each line or let grep output for all files and you post-process it

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for your suggestions, are you able to provide an example please?

Comment: Do the files you are searching in only have 1 word per line?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, there is >1 word per line

Comment: Is a "term" a string or a regexp? Should the values in the output be the "term" you searched for, or the string from each file that matched the term, or something else? How many input files do you have? How large are they? What does the output look like if every term is NOT found in every file? [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output otherwise it's highly unlikely that you'll get the best solution to your problem since we can't tell what your real problem is from what you've provided so far so we're just guessing.

Comment: Why's [MATLAB] suddenly involved? Sure, MATLAB can [even make you dinner, if you know how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri), but I don't see the added benefit of using it here. I suggest you remove it from your question, or make an honest attempt at coding this in MATLAB first. (Although that'd be a separate question, to not invalidate the existing answers here).

Comment: Why provide a bounty that's 1/3 of your whole reputation and then not answer the questions and provide the other missing information that'd let someone provide the right answer? I don't get it. Ah well....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use awk's pattern matching to find the single LOCUS and any tRNA mentions.

get locus accession for free with awks field splitting as the second item

split out the tRNA products (if any) enclosed in quotes and associate them with the locus accession.

keep track of the max number of tRNA for a locus, this will be number of rows output (plus header)

After all GenBank records in all files given on the command line are processed.

output each locus accession as the header
then for every row possible
 output any tRNA product associated beneath its locus accession.

script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/gawk -f

/^LOCUS       /{RefSeq = $2}

/^                     \/product="tRNA-/{
    split($1, tRNA, "\"");
    head[RefSeq]++;  
    LOCUS[RefSeq,head[RefSeq]] = tRNA[2]
    if(head[RefSeq] > rows)
        rows = head[RefSeq] 
}

END{
    # to ensure constant order
    cols = asorti(head)
    for(i=1;i<=cols;i++)
        header = header "|" head[i]
    print substr(header, 2)

    for(r=1; r<=rows; r++){
        row = ""
        for(c=1; c<=cols; c++)
            row = row "|" LOCUS[head[c],r]
        print substr(row, 2)
    }
}
```

Directory
note: the gbff I grabbed have multiple GenBank records per file

```
 ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 tomc tomc 1724943 Mar 31 23:21 bacteria.24.genomic.gbff
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomc tomc 3216313 Mar 31 23:53 bacteria.431.genomic.gbff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomc tomc     487 Mar 31 23:51 locus_trna_transpose.awk
```

Result: 
note: using pipe as a field separator to make it easier to see

```
./locus_trna_transpose.awk bacteria*.gbff
 NZ_AWIQ01000161|NZ_AWIQ01000167|NZ_AWIQ01000183|NZ_AWKN01000226|NZ_AWKN01000319|NZ_AWLJ01000031|NZ_AWLJ01000043|NZ_AWLJ01000050|NZ_JORA01000025|NZ_JORA01000026|NZ_JORA01000030|NZ_JORA01000031|NZ_JORA01000032|NZ_JORA01000034|NZ_JORA01000036|NZ_JORA01000037
tRNA-binding|tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Met|tRNA-Asn|tRNA-binding|tRNA-Val|tRNA-Leu|tRNA-binding|tRNA-Pro|tRNA-Val|tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Met|tRNA-Phe|tRNA-Met|tRNA-Met
|||||tRNA-Val|||tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Val|tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Arg|tRNA-Met||tRNA-binding|tRNA-Leu
||||||||tRNA-Ala|tRNA-Val||tRNA-Ser|tRNA-Met|||
||||||||tRNA-Ala|tRNA-Val|||tRNA-Gly|||
||||||||tRNA-Ala|tRNA-Lys|||tRNA-modifying|||
||||||||tRNA-Ala|||||||
```

For those playing along, 
these input files are grabbed as being smallish from

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/release/bacteria/

Comment: This looks exactly what I need, thanks!! I am just having some trouble running it. I have saved the script as `locus_trna_transpose.awk` and put it in the directory with my .gbff files. I have run `chmod ugo+x ./locus_trna_transpose.awk.sh` is that right? When I try to run the script I get `bad interpreter: Permission denied`. Thanks for your help, this is great!

Comment: I am not on a mac,  but you need to have the first line (called shebang line starts with  '#!' )  point to your awk.  you might try typing  w/o quotes  "which awk"  or  "locate awk"  and see what that gets you.. You could also try "#!/usr/bin/env awk -f"  as  env be available to find it for you

Comment: for execute permissions you can also just do "chmod +x  script.name"

Comment: also can run it by typing "awk -f locus_trna_transpose.awk bacteria.*.gbff"   and it will ignore the shebang line and use whatever awk your system already knows about (which should be fine)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

I think my original approach is too resource intensive for the number of files you have, so here is a less intensive version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't barf of no matching files, and allow upper and lower case
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

# Loop through all ".txt" files whose names start with "seq"
j=0
for f in seq*txt; do
   # Generate output file name
   printf -v out "Z%05d.tmp" $j
   grep -E "LOCUS\s*NZ_AP013294|tRNA" "$f" > "$out"
   ((j=j+1))
done

# Paste all output files together in columns
paste Z*tmp > result.txt

# Remove temp files
rm Z*tmp
```

I only named all the temporary files beginning with "Z" so they only show up at the end in your file browser.

So, save the above in a file called "go" in your HOME directory, then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Then you can run it in any directory by doing:

```
cd some/place/where/your/files/are
$HOME/go
```

---

**Original Answer**

I think this gives what you want:

```
parallel 'grep "term" {} > {#}.tmp' ::: *txt ; paste *tmp ; rm *tmp
```

**Sample Output**

```
term1   term1
term3   term2
        term3
```

That says... *"Look for `term` in all files whose names end in `txt`, saving the output from the first in `1.tmp`, the second in `2.tmp` and so on. At the end, paste all the temporary files together in columns and remove them."*

You need to know that, with **GNU Parallel**, `{}` stands for *"the current parameter/file"* and that `{#}` stands for *"the current job number"*, and finally that `:::` separates the parameters from the commands to be applied.

---

You can also do it without temporary files. Prefix each line of `grep` output with the **GNU Parallel** job number, then pass the lot in **Perl** to strip off the job number and replace it with 8 * that many spaces:

```
parallel --tag-string {#} 'grep "term" {}' ::: *txt | perl -plne 's/^(\d+)\s*/" " x (8*($1-1))/e'

term1
term3
        term1
        term2
        term3
```

**Perl** is shipped with all Macs.

For anyone who is interested, this is a variant of the [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), or the Lisp *decorate-sort-undecorate* idiom.

---

I install **GNU Parallel** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```

Though it can also be installed very simply without **homebrew** since it is *only* a **Perl** script and all Macs come with **Perl**:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ ) | bash
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am getting the error `paste: 1226.tmp: Too many open files`. Term1 and term2 do not have the same regular expression. In reality, I am searching for the term `LOCUS` (of which there is one in each file) and the term `tRNA-` (of which there are many in each file). I have around 2000 files. These files are .gbff files (from GenBank). So, is this correct? `parallel 'grep -e "LOCUS" -e "tRNA-" {} > {#}.tmp' ::: *gbff ; paste *tmp ; rm *tmp` .  What is the output file called?

Comment: Maybe try `ulimit -S -n 2048` before runnng `parallel`.

Comment: Or try copying a few hundred files to a separate directory and see how far off we are... it may be that we need to do it differently.

Comment: I'll give that a go. How can I save the output to out.txt rather than print on screen?

Comment: I did copy 10 files to another directory and it sort of works I think - it prints to screen though so slightly hard to tell, even when I paste it to a txt file

Comment: I did try `. out.txt` (I assumed it was that) but the .txt file is empty

Comment: yes, unfortunately it is empty...  here is an example of one of my files https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_AP013294 (click 'send to', 'file' save format as 'full genbank file'. I have ~2000 of these. I just want `LOCUS  NZ_AP013294` and then every time it has `tRNA-`, e.g. `tRNA-Glu`

Comment: @user2861089 are you saying that what you actually want to search for are blocks of text where `LOCUS NZ_AP013294` appears on one line and then `tRNA-` appears on a different line? If so, what would the output be - `LOCUS NZ_AP013294` or `tRNA-` or something else? Is there always just one LOCUS line in each input file or multiple? Does `tRNA-` need to appear in some specific context or just anywhere at all in the file? Really **think** about your requirements and then update your question to state them with a concrete example.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for this! It isn't quite right, but getting there - I am trying to edit your code. It isn't quite getting everything in the right columns. I have updated my question to be more clear. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear but given one possible interpretation of your requirements, this might be what you want:

```
awk '
/LOCUS/ {
    locus[++numCols] = $0
}
/tRNA/ {
    rnas[++rowNrs[numCols],numCols] = $0
    numRows = (rowNrs[numCols] > numRows ? rowNrs[numCols] : numRows)
}
END {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", locus[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", rnas[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
' *.txt
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide sample input/output we could test against.

If that's not what you want then whatever it is you DO want will be equally trivial but you'll have to tell/show us what that is in your question first to get a solution for it.

Comment: It's getting better but you **still** haven't provided the sample input that would produce your posted expected output. Providing a reference to some file repository that contains some data that we don't have the expected output for isn't useful. Just show concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

This type of processing is really beyond the capabilities of `grep`. You're better off creating a small customized script that does exactly what you want. I would use `python` and `pandas` to accomplish the task. Here is an implementation, based on my current understanding of your description.

#### Code

```
import re
import sys
import pandas as pd

# Regular expressions; adjust as necessary
regex_locus = re.compile('LOCUS\s+(\S+)')
regex_trna  = re.compile('"(tRNA-.*)"')

# Aggregate results in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

total_files = len(sys.argv[1:])

# Iterate over the files given on the command line
for index, file in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):

    print("Processing {:4d}/{:4d}: {}".format(index + 1, total_files, file))

    # Per file variables.
    locus = None
    trna  = []

    # Open the file for reading
    with open(file) as fd:

        # Find LOCUS value
        for line in fd:
            match = regex_locus.search(line)

            if match:
                locus = match.group(1)
                
                # Done with this section
                break

        # Find tRNA values
        for line in fd:
            match = regex_trna.search(line)

            if match:
                trna.append(match.group(1))

    # Done with this file
    if locus is not None:
        # Add the entry for this file. Convert the list to a pandas Series to account for differing lengths.
        df[locus] = pd.Series(trna)

# Write out the final DataFrame as csv
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

# And as text...
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fd:
    df.to_string(fd, index=False)
```

#### Notes

- I'm assuming the LOCUS line always occurs before the tRNA values. This seems to be the format from your example file.
- The code generates `output.csv` and `output.txt`. The output format is basically free since the data is in a DataFrame.
- If the script was named `build_table.py`, you would invoke it as: `python build_table.py *.gbff`